# Do we plan a strategy?

Tags: verbs, semantics, collocation

Is it grammatically correct to say :

> "He planned a strategy".

Comment: *Grammatically,* it is equally correct to use absolutely any transitive verb in that sentence. He planned a strategy, he wore a strategy, he ate a strategy, he married a strategy. The question is whether it makes *sense*. Your question should be reworded to be about collocations and semantics, not about grammar.

Comment: It makes grammatical sense, however I would be inclined to use 'prepared', 'developed' or 'concocted', But I have nothing to support why, just personal preference I suppose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Strategy**

> a **plan** of action designed to achieve a long-term or overall aim.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

He planned a strategy==> He planned a plan of action...

Now, planning a plan doesn't make sense(though it is grammatically correct to use any transitive verb before the object as RegDwight mentioned)

It's better to say, "He strategized" or "He planned".

Other options are: "He came up with/prepared a strategy", "He put forth a strategy"

Comment: +1 You said it as well or better (and using the same source) just as I was clicking my post.

Comment: Planning a plan makes perfect sense, as does mapping a map.

Comment: @ pazzo - RE: planning a plan & mapping a map. Sense *can* be found there, but not eloquence. Sounds distinctly like stuttering.

Comment: Your last suggestion is also a little repetitive, as it translates to 'He put forth a long-term-plan-of-action plan of action.' Better to just say, 'He put forth a strategy.'

Comment: That would suggest he divulged the strategy Natheniel. Also there are instances where it might be useful to separate the act from its result in a larger narrative, esp. since an act doesn't guarantee a result. "He planned a plan" implies that he actually came up with one. "He planned." implies he just attempted to do so.  Also is that the definition given demonstrates more than just 'any' plan but rather suggests a complex one, so there is a distinction to be made. There's worse in common use too, like "building a building."

Comment: It is not enough to plan the plan: you also have to walk the walk and talk the talk.

Comment: @pazzo: I don't see the need for repetition. The noun form(the talk, the walk) developed from the verb(talk, walk) and vice versa(the map==>map, the plan==>plan). When you plan, it is understood that a plan is planned, when you walk, you are obviously walking a walk. It surely makes sense but I cannot understand why you need to repeat the same word.

Comment: @pazzo - [planning a plan] Now you have me singing "Matchmaker, Matchmaker" (-: